# Bind the Text Property of Textblock to a Combobox selectedItem with different DataContext in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I have a Data Grid that is bound to a object of type MyStaff. Apart from other properties MyStaff contains a column named LookupID. Now, in my ViewModel I have a collection Named Lookups that have a description for each LookupID.

I have a Template column that has a Textblock in Cell Template and Combobox in CellEdit Template. How do I bind the Textblock so that it dsiplays the description from ComboBox based on LookupID.

I know it would be pretty simple if the datacontext for both the Textblock and ComboBox were simple but that is not the case.

I have tried this but this doesn't work. Any suggestions? Also would appreciate any information on how to best use different Data Context for different controls in Silverlight. For this I have added a static resource pointing to the ViewModel Class.

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action Point"
                            Width="500"
                            CanUserReorder="False"
                            HeaderStyle="{StaticResource dthFull2}"
                            IsReadOnly="False">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding ElementName=LookupList,
                               Path=SelectedItem.Description}"
                MinHeight="24"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Padding="2"
                TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <my:AutoCompleteComboBox x:Name="LookupList"
                FilterMode="Custom" Margin="2,0,0,0"
                SelectedValue="{Binding LookupID, Mode=TwoWay}"
                SelectedValuePath="LookupID"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AnalysisLookupList.Values,
                                      Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>                  
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Usually you would have a public property in the row's ViewModel and both Controls (from CellTemplate and CellEditingTemplate) can bind to it and thus are in sync. And don't confuse the ComboBox' ItemsSource with the DataContext, they can be completely different objects without causing any problems.

Comment: So what is the DataContext / ViewModel for the row in this case? Is there a reason to not use a public property on the ViewModel?

Comment: The Data Grid is bound to a Collection called MyStaff and the Selected Row is bound to a property called Selected Staff. The Selected Staff among other things contains a column named LookupID. In my ViewModel I have a collection named LookupList. Now what I am trying to achieve is that the LookupID column in grid displays description of lookup based on lookupID. If I bind the combobox directly to the collection I get an error saying "Could not find property on Mystaff", which I think is because the Data grId is bound to a collection MyStaff and MySTaff has no idea about LookupList.

Comment: ... So I am passing the ViewModel as Static Resource and am binding the combo box to LookupList. Have a look at this article http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls and this Section "Using a Static Resource When Binding Nested Controls"

Comment: Sorry but that does not make things any clearer. I think it's best if you just add the relevant ViewModel code to your question (it will be sufficient to show the property names and types, no PropertyChangedImplementation please).